# Re-rendering react component after user action

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a basic job list probably 20 elements per page, every element has like icon , according to data from db i will fill it red or grey, pretty simple to implement, but how to do it good ? i mean , what should happened when user will click like button ? in my mind i have to do redux call to be sure that i will update this value in db , but what should i do in front end ? should i get whole list again from db and re-render the whole component? or i have to change value of like by myself ?

Answer (score 0):

Its gonna be a bad idea to update the whole component just for showing the like icon. SO what you can do here is, when the user clicks the like button, update a state for that particular reusable component and make a call to redux to update the DB

Answer (score 0):

How is stored your list? In redux ?
I assume each item should have a `liked` property, which is `true/false`

So when you click the "like" button, you have to dispatch an action to call your backend to update your db, and toggle this boolean in your Redux store. (btw Redux do not update your db)

You can look at [redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) on how to make a call to your back-end and update your redux store with thunk middleware